# Why isn't this transition working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Singularity</title>

<style>

body {
background-color: grey;
}

#boxOne {
position:relative;
height:150px;
width:150px;
background-color: black;

}

</style>
 <script>
  function playOne(){
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.left = "30px";
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.transition = "all 4s";
 }
 </script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="boxOne" onclick="playOne()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works as far as the box moving left to right. I've used `style.transition` successfully before to move a circle slowly from left to right but this box does not behave the way im trying to get it to. The box should not instantly move from left to right, it should take 4s as stated in the style.transition script. Dont understand what im doing wrong.

Comment: No, it does work and correctly animates. https://jsfiddle.net/bx9x8c3y/

Comment: no it doesnt, it moves from left to right instantly.

Comment: Hm, sorry - looks like it does in Safari and doesn't in Chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to set also a value to start from in your style sheet (all browsers won't assume a default value)

```js
function playOne() {
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.left = "30px";
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.transition = "all 4s"; //might be coherent to declare this at first 
  //or even straight in the style sheet 
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
#boxOne {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  left: 0;
  /* added this, so calculation can be done from an earlier css value*/
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxOne" onclick="playOne()"></div>
```

Comment: Btw, the initial example works in Safari (so not all browsers).

Comment: @nicael that's what i meant :won't == will not (english not my mother language, did not study it either, just picked it up so i guess i sound funny sometimes :)

Comment: GCyrillus i am so appreciative ! thank you it works now. and now i see why i was able to get this to work before, i had start values on those other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a starting a value of left so it will work properly

```
    <head>
<title>Singularity</title>

<style>

body {
background-color: grey;
}

#boxOne {
position:relative;
height:150px;
width:150px;
background-color: black;
left:0px; /*value left added*/

}

</style>
 <script>
  function playOne(){
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.left = "250px";
  document.getElementById("boxOne").style.transition = "all 4s";
 }
 </script>


</head>

<body>
<div id="boxOne" onclick="playOne()"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx osama, someone did answer right before you did, but you are correct as well. i deeply apreciate your assistance

Comment: No problem Brother :)